# Solving vector ordinary differential equations in python with scipy odeint

Tags: python, vector, matplotlib, scipy, ode

I'm trying to solve and ode that involves vectors and can't come out with a feasible answer.  So i split it into 6 components, one for each time derivative of a component, and one for each time derivative of a velocity component.  The first value seems reasonable but then it jumps to to numbers in the millions and I'm not sure why. I'm honestly not really sure how to do this in the first place and am just giving it a shot right now. I couldn't seem to find any info on it online and could use some help or some links if there are examples of this type of problem.  Any info would be much appreciated on how to get this to solve the ODE.

```
def dr_dt(y, t):
"""Integration of the governing vector differential equation.
d2r_dt2 = -(mu/R^3)*r with d2r_dt2 and r as vecotrs.
Initial position and velocity are given.
y[0:2] = position components
y[3:] = velocity components"""

    G = 6.672*(10**-11)
    M = 5.972*(10**24)
    mu = G*M
    r = np.sqrt(y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2) 

    dy0 = y[3]
    dy1 = y[4]
    dy2 = y[5]
    dy3 = -(mu / (r**3)) * y[0]
    dy4 = -(mu / (r**3)) * y[1]
    dy5 = -(mu / (r**3)) * y[2]
    return [dy0, dy3, dy1, dy4, dy2, dy5]
```

After this is solved, I want to plot it. It should come out to an ellipse but to be honest I'm not exactly sure how to do that either.  I was thinking of taking the magnitude of the position and then plotting it with time.  If there's a better way of doing this please feel free to let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if your `y[:3]` is position and `y[3:]` is velocity, then `dr_dt` function should return the components in exactly this order. Second, to plot the trajectory we can either use excellent matplotlib `mplot3d` module, or omit `z`th component of position and velocity (so our motion is on XY plane), and plot `y` versus `x`. The sample code (with corrected order of return values) is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def dr_dt(y, t):
    """Integration of the governing vector differential equation.
    d2r_dt2 = -(mu/R^3)*r with d2r_dt2 and r as vecotrs.
    Initial position and velocity are given.
    y[0:2] = position components
    y[3:] = velocity components"""

    G = 6.672*(10**-11)
    M = 5.972*(10**24)
    mu = G*M
    r = np.sqrt(y[0]**2 + y[1]**2 + y[2]**2).

    dy0 = y[3]
    dy1 = y[4]
    dy2 = y[5]
    dy3 = -(mu / (r**3)) * y[0]
    dy4 = -(mu / (r**3)) * y[1]
    dy5 = -(mu / (r**3)) * y[2]
    return [dy0, dy1, dy2, dy3, dy4, dy5]

t = np.arange(0, 100000, 0.1)
y0 = [7.e6, 0., 0., 0., 1.e3, 0.]
y = odeint(dr_dt, y0, t)
plt.plot(y[:,0], y[:,1])
plt.show()
```

This yields a nice ellipse:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, that helps a lot.  I thought I might of had those out of order, but the main problem was when I noticed you kept `y0` as a list.  I had mine as an array, I should've put that in the code when I posted it, my mistake. Once i fixed that it looks as though more relevant information is returning.  Only problem i have now is that it won't plot correctly. I have `y0 = [-4069.503, 2861.786, 4483.608, -5.114, -5.691, -1.500]` for input.  And when it returns, and I plot it. It only comes out as a line going from the top left to bottom right.  Same for 3D as well when I tried that.

Comment: As your calculations are in SI, you need your initial velocities be in m/s (and positions in m, respectively). The velocity of 5 m/s is nowhere near the escape velocity, so you see the trajectory of a body falling on Earth.

Comment: Unbelievable, totally worked.  Thanks so much man, I can't believe it was such a simple mistake like that.  Really appreciate your help.